# Multiple versions on Docker image

Tags: docker, containers

Let's suppose I have a project where I have a C program, named Fox in version 2.2, that I want to test using different OS and with or without LLVM. How should I name my containers to tag those different versions ?

- fox-debian8-llvm:2.2 ?
- fox:debian7-llvm-2.2 ?
- fox-centos:7.4-2.2 ?
- fox-llvm-debian:2.2-x-8 ?

I could not find real guidlines concerning this issue, just tagging for one project... Is there a good way to do this ??

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you checked labels?

Comment: I have checked it, but if I make two images with the same name but different labels, it only keeps the last that has been built. So I still don't really know how to differentiate them :/

Comment: There are no guidelines, you are free to name ur images whatever makes sense to you.

Comment: You can tag your image whatever you like. But still, you can refer different images on docker hub. I would like to tag like

debian8/fox-llvm:2.2